# jQuery.ajax returns error: Unexpected token with Error Message: parseerror?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery.ajax routine that calls a php script. The php script does a lookup on the Google search API and returns json to the calling ajax script.

The script works fine on 99% of installs, however, on a few, when I call:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
alert('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus);
}
```

It returns:

> HTTP Error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token** < | Error Message:
>   **parsererror**

How can I troubleshoot this using javascript console or chrome developer tools? Code stub is below...

```
var result='';
jQuery.ajax
({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: <?php  echo '"' .plugins_url('/script.php', __FILE__); ?>?Query="+ jQuery('#search_keyword').val(),
    success: function(data)
    {       
        //do something with results
    },

    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(arguments);
        alert('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown+' | Error Message: '+textStatus);
        return;
    }
});
```

UPDATE: Console.log's OBJECT error reads:

```
responseText: "<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  array_map() [<a href='function.array-map'>function.array-map</a>]: Argument #2 should be an array in <b>/filepath/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />↵<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/filepath/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />↵No Records Returned. Search may be down. Wait a few minutes"
```

Comment: Sounds like you've got malformed json coming back. The `<` would hint that maybe it's an html tag wrapped around the json?

Comment: Which locale? Which is the URL you fire for the json return? Maybe you get XML instead? Please provide more information.

Comment: @hakre: thanks for checking this out. I've just updated the question.

Comment: Maybe you should build the URL in a variable first, then echo it out and tell us, so it's possible to obtain / see the json. Next to that it might help you to debug your script.

Comment: I can get the json and paste it here. But it fails regardless of what I search on. Json is different every time, but script always fails.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You probably have HTML returning where it was not supposed to for the JSON.

Try `console.log(arguments);` before the alert to see what is returned

Comment: Thanks Neal, when I view the javascript console after inserting that,I get what appears to be the same message there: [ Object, "parseerror", SyntaxError ]

Comment: @RegEdit -- look at what is in the `Object`

Comment: +1 Neal, now I have some clues. Just updated the question with the result.

Comment: @RegEdit and there is ur answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

This tell you where is the issue is

```
responseText: "<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  array_map() [<a href='function.array-map'>function.array-map</a>]: Argument #2 should be an array in <b>/filepath/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />↵<br />↵<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/filepath/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php</b> on line <b>90</b><br />↵No Records Returned. Search may be down. Wait a few minutes"
```

Most likely in some installations it behaves in a different way because of different [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) settings

In production environments error reporting should be off, but as a rule of thumb your code should never emit any warning or notice.

In any case you should handle your errors better especially in

```
Argument #2 should be an array in /filepath/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php on line 75
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /filepath/wpcontent/plugins/test/test.php on line 90
```

Both these warnings are caused by the fact that your variable is not an array (maybe false or null), usually this can be fixed with an [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) check before accessing the array or by **always** checking the return value of all functions.